# How do you generate the DDL that created a DB2 LUW database?

Tags: db2, scripting, db2-luw

There are various options for `db2look` you can use to see the DDL for just about every object in the database except the command that created the database itself.  Is there any way with `db2look`, or perhaps with some other system command, where you can see the exact command structure that created a database?

Comment: There are options on db2look that let you generate those commands if I remember correctly.

Comment: @MaxVernon - you have the DB2 for z link. OP is asking for LUW.

Comment: @RobertEJohnson - here is the link for the documentation on db2look. Multiple parameters depending on what you want: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html?lang=en Be careful as some of the parameters don't match together or order may matter. See Ember Crooks blog (db2commerce.com) on db2look.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum requirement is to have DB2 10.1.4 or DB2 10.5 installed.

> -createdb: Generate the CREATE DATABASE command that was used to create the source database

`db2look -d sample -createdb`

Comment: I can see the -createdb option in the documentation, but it does not seem to work with my express-c 10.5 fixpak 1. Do you know if this option requires a certain license?

Comment: It may have been introduced in 10.5.3 or 10.5.4, which came out shortly before and shortly after 10.1.4, respectively.